# How do I authorize a Google user in Python backend with ID token coming from iOS application?

Tags: python, ios, swift, django, google-authentication

### Solution

So I don't think its a surprise to anyone but Google's documentation is god awful. It's so scattered and the Python docs still reference their old depreciated library. Anyways.

So what I really needed to look at was this link ["Enabling Server Side Access for your App"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access#python). This is not linked to anywhere. Keep in mind this is entirely different than ["Authenticating with a Backend Server"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth?ver=swift)

This was a start. On the iOS side of things, we need to specify the server or backend's `client_id`.

```swift
...

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = SBConstants.Google.IOS_CLIENT_ID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID = SBConstants.Google.SERVER_CLIENT_ID

...
```

And capture `serverAuthCode` from the `sign` method inside your sign-in delegate.

```swift
...

self.googleUser.userID = user.userID
self.googleUser.token = user.authentication.idToken
self.googleUser.serverAuthCode = user.serverAuthCode

...
```

Now when you want to perform some action in the backend on behalf of the frontend, we pass the captured `serverAuthCode` and send it as a parameter.

That was the easy part. In the backend, Google seems to have 13 different OAuth2 libraries for Python documented. Their example uses `oauth2client` which of course is deprecated.

What we want to use is their 'new' library [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

When the `auth_token` is passed to the backend we need to check if the user already has an access token in our database. If it does, we need to refresh. Otherwise, we need to request a new access token based on the `auth_code`. After much trial and error, here is the code to do so:

```py
# we have record of this user
# we have record of this user
if user.exists:                                 
    # create new credentials, and refresh
    credentials = Credentials(                
        token=user.token,                     
        refresh_token=user.refresh_token,     
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,                  
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,          
        token_uri='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

    # now we have an access token       
    credentials.refresh(requests.Request())   
                                                
else:                            

    # get the auth_token              
    token_obj = json.loads(request.body)      
    code = token_obj.get('auth_code')         

    # request access token given auth_token                        
    auth_flow = flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(creds, scopes=scopes) 
    auth_flow.fetch_token(code=code)       

    # now have access token   
    credentials = auth_flow.credentials
```

**A warning:** Pass or fail, the `auth_token` is only good for one request. This totally burned me. This also means once you have a successful backend interaction, you must store the user's token information to then request a refresh *not* a new access token.

Hope this helps someone.

---

### Original Post

Following the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server), I am trying to authenticate a user in my iOS app and pass their ID token to my backend. The backend handles the Google API interactions for the iOS app.

I am missing how to actually authenticate that user in the backend. I read over the docs [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#identity-tokens) regarding ID tokens but I am confused on where the service account comes into play.

Current endpoint:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def google_token_info(request):
    try:
        token_obj = json.loads(request.body)
        token = token_obj['id_token']

        id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), settings.IOS_CLIENT_ID)
        
        # create session here - how?
```

This is all working fine. The ID info returns the expected decrypted JWT contents, and I have the user's unique Google ID at this point.

While testing I had authentication set up via my backend. I had code like this:

```py
def google_auth(request):
    web_flow = flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(creds, scopes=scopes)
    web_flow.redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('api.auth:oauth_callback'))
    auth_url, state = web_flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', include_granted_scopes='true', prompt='consent')
    request.session['state'] = state
    return redirect(auth_url)

def oauth_callback(request):

    success_flow = flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(creds, scopes=scopes, state=request.session.get('state'))
    success_flow.redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('api.auth:oauth_callback'))

    auth_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
    success_flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=auth_response)

    credentials = success_flow.credentials
    if not request.session.get('google_credentials'):
        request.session['google_credentials'] = _credentials_to_dict(credentials)

    return redirect(reverse('api.auth:success'))
```

Which setup session credentials for the user. I'm assuming I need something similar, but I am unsure how to create a session without actual credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

So I don't think its a surprise to anyone but Google's documentation is god awful. It's so scattered and the Python docs still reference their old depreciated library. Anyways.

So what I really needed to look at was this link ["Enabling Server Side Access for your App"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access#python). This is not linked to anywhere. Keep in mind this is entirely different than ["Authenticating with a Backend Server"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth?ver=swift)

This was a start. On the iOS side of things, we need to specify the server or backend's `client_id`.

```swift
...

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = SBConstants.Google.IOS_CLIENT_ID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID = SBConstants.Google.SERVER_CLIENT_ID

...
```

And capture `serverAuthCode` from the `sign` method inside your sign-in delegate.

```swift
...

self.googleUser.userID = user.userID
self.googleUser.token = user.authentication.idToken
self.googleUser.serverAuthCode = user.serverAuthCode

...
```

Now when you want to perform some action in the backend on behalf of the frontend, we pass the captured `serverAuthCode` and send it as a parameter.

That was the easy part. In the backend, Google seems to have 13 different OAuth2 libraries for Python documented. Their example uses `oauth2client` which of course is deprecated.

What we want to use is their 'new' library [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

When the `auth_token` is passed to the backend we need to check if the user already has an access token in our database. If it does, we need to refresh. Otherwise, we need to request a new access token based on the `auth_code`. After much trial and error, here is the code to do so:

```py
# we have record of this user
# we have record of this user
if user.exists:                                 
    # create new credentials, and refresh
    credentials = Credentials(                
        token=user.token,                     
        refresh_token=user.refresh_token,     
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,                  
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,          
        token_uri='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

    # now we have an access token       
    credentials.refresh(requests.Request())   
                                                
else:                            

    # get the auth_token              
    token_obj = json.loads(request.body)      
    code = token_obj.get('auth_code')         

    # request access token given auth_token                        
    auth_flow = flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(creds, scopes=scopes) 
    auth_flow.fetch_token(code=code)       

    # now have access token   
    credentials = auth_flow.credentials
```

**A warning:** Pass or fail, the `auth_token` is only good for one request. This totally burned me. This also means once you have a successful backend interaction, you must store the user's token information to then request a refresh *not* a new access token.

Comment: You state that `Pass or fail, the auth_token is only good for one request`. Why do you think that? That is an incorrect statement. Google OAuth Access Tokens are good for 3600 seconds by default.

Comment: The code and that comment are not referring to Google OAuth Access Tokens. The code and question are surrounding server-side authorization from client applications. The access token is explicitly stated to be one-time use in Google's scattered documentation. See [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) "... passing a *one-time* authorization code from your client to your server ..."